# How to test controller action that serializes a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nunit, moq

Alright so I am trying to test a controller result to make sure it is returning the right values but I am running into a number of problems with mocking controller contexts. All I want to do is test if someone enters a number on a page if the JsonResult is success = true.  However in the controller I serialize a partial view and return some HTML that contains all the data that is pertinent to the request number.  I am comfortable with setting up the expected results in the json result, but I can't even get the test to advance to that far.  The test gets hung up when serializing the partial view.  I don't really care to test that but I don't know how to work around the result of that function other than the create some fakes for the controllercontext and let it search for an serialize the view.

Here is the controller

```
[HttpPost]
[RecaptchaControlMvc.CaptchaValidator]
public JsonResult GetPublicInformation(PublicPortalViewModel model, bool captchaValid)
{
    if (captchaValid == true)
    {
        //check to see if their is a request number to look up the request by
        if (model.RequestNumber != null)
        {
            //fill model data using by calling the service
            model = _service.GetPublicPortalData(model);
            var content = base.SerializeView("DisplayPublicInformation", model);
            return Json(new { success = true, htmlContent = content });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, htmlContent = "<span style=\"color: red;\">No request was found with that number, please enter a valid request number.</span>" });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, htmlContent = "<span style=\"color: red;\">Please enter a valid Captcha Value</span>" });
    }
}
```

Specifically I am having problems with this line:

```
var content = base.SerializeView("DisplayPublicInformation", model);
```

Here is the definition of that function:

```
protected internal virtual string SerializeView(string viewName, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    this.ViewData.Model = model;

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        // keep getting null reference errors on this line when I write my tests .
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(this.ControllerContext, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(this.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, this.ViewData, this.TempData, sw);
        // render the view into the stringwriter class
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        // output the rendered string
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Here is my test which I apologize for being so messy but I wanted to post where I am at currently.  I know there is more code than needed.

```
private PartialViewResult _result;
private Mock<HttpContextBase> _mockHttpContext;
private HttpContextBase _httpContext;
private RouteData _routeData;
private RouteData _parentRouteData;

protected Mock<HttpContextBase> HttpContextBaseMock;
protected Mock<HttpRequestBase> HttpRequestMock;
protected Mock<HttpResponseBase> HttpResponseMock;

[Test]
public void GetPublicInformationValidRequestNumber()
{
    var sut = new PublicPortalController();
    SetupRouteData();
    HttpContextBaseMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    HttpContextBaseMock.SetupAllProperties();
    HttpRequestMock = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    HttpResponseMock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
    HttpContextBaseMock.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(HttpRequestMock.Object);
    HttpContextBaseMock.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(HttpResponseMock.Object);

    var browser = new Mock<HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var cookies = new HttpCookieCollection();
    var items = new ListDictionary();

    var mockViewEngine = new Mock<IViewEngine>();

    Mock<IView> view = new Mock<IView>();
    var viewResult = new ViewEngineResult(new[] { "location1", "location2" });

    mockViewEngine
        .Setup(x => x.FindView(It.IsAny<ControllerContext>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>()))
        .Returns(viewResult);

    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(mockViewEngine.Object);

    browser.Setup(b => b.IsMobileDevice).Returns(false);
    request.Setup(r => r.Cookies).Returns(cookies);
    request.Setup(r => r.ValidateInput());
    request.Setup(r => r.UserAgent).Returns("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11");
    response.Setup(r => r.Cookies).Returns(cookies);

    request.Setup(r => r.Browser).Returns(browser.Object);
    HttpContextBaseMock.Setup(ctx => ctx.Items).Returns(items);

    var routes = new RouteCollection();

    var ControllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>(HttpContextBaseMock.Object, _routeData, sut);

    var controller = new Mock<PublicPortalController>();

    ControllerContext.SetupGet(c => c.Controller).Returns(controller.Object);
    ControllerContext.SetupGet(c => c.HttpContext).Returns(HttpContextBaseMock.Object);

    sut.Url = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(HttpContextBaseMock.Object, _routeData), routes);
    sut.ControllerContext = ControllerContext.Object;
    var basecontroller = new Mock<RequestITBaseController>();

    var fakePublicPortalViewModel = new Mock<PublicPortalViewModel>();
    fakePublicPortalViewModel.Setup(m => m.RequestNumber).Returns("23");
    bool captchaValid = true;

    basecontroller.Setup(c => c.SerializeView("DisplayPublicInformation", fakePublicPortalViewModel)).Returns("");

    var result = sut.GetPublicInformation(fakePublicPortalViewModel.Object, captchaValid) as JsonResult;
    dynamic jsonObject = result.Data;

    Assert.IsTrue(jsonObject.success);
}

private void SetupRouteData()
{
    SetupParentRouteData();
    var viewContext = new ViewContext { RouteData = _parentRouteData };

    _routeData = new RouteData();
    _routeData.Values.Add("controller", "PublicPortalController");
    _routeData.Values.Add("action", "GetPublicInformation");
    _routeData.DataTokens["ParentActionViewContext"] = viewContext;
}

private void SetupParentRouteData()
{
    _parentRouteData = new RouteData();
    _parentRouteData.Values.Add("controller", "PublicPortalController");
    _parentRouteData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependencies, gotta love dependencies, better yet *static* dependencies.

If the underlying code in `SerializeView` is not that important for the unit test, then the easiest thing to do is to abstract out that method into another type and inject instead of inheriting it from a base class....

Something like this:

```
public interface IViewHelper
{
    string SerializeView(ControllerContext context, ViewDataDictionary viewData, TempDataDictionary tempData,
        string viewName, object model);
}    

public class ViewHelper : IViewHelper
{
    private readonly ViewEngineCollection _viewEngines = ViewEngines.Engines;

    public string SerializeView(ControllerContext context, ViewDataDictionary viewData, TempDataDictionary tempData, string viewName, object model)
    {
        viewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            // keep getting null reference errors on this line when I write my tests .
            var viewResult = _viewEngines.FindPartialView(context, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewResult.View, viewData, tempData, sw);
            // render the view into the stringwriter class
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            // output the rendered string
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
public PublicPortalController(..., IViewHelper helper)
{
    _helper = helper;
}

....

public JsonResult GetPublicInformation(PublicPortalViewModel model, bool captchaValid)
{
    ....
            //fill model data using by calling the service
            model = _service.GetPublicPortalData(model);
            var content = _helper.SerializeView(ControllerContext, ViewData, TempData, "DisplayPublicInformation", model);
            return Json(new { success = true, htmlContent = content });
   ....
}
```

Now in your test all you have to do is Mock out `IViewHelper` and you should be away laughing:

```
var mockHelper = new Mock<IViewHelper>();
        mockHelper.Setup(
            x =>
                x.SerializeView(It.IsAny<ControllerContext>(), It.IsAny<ViewDataDictionary>(),
                    It.IsAny<TempDataDictionary>(), "", It.IsAny<PublicPortalViewModel>())).Returns("<html></html>");

        var sut = new PublicPortalController(mockService, ... , mockHelper.Object);

        var fakePublicPortalViewModel = new PublicPortalViewModel{RequestNumber = "23"};
        bool captchaValid = true;

        var result = sut.Index(fakePublicPortalViewModel, captchaValid) as JsonResult;
        dynamic jsonObject = result.Data;
```

Comment: Hahahahahah, laughing away indeed.  I greatly appreciate your answer, however this is a little bit new for me to split up a pre-existing function and add in a new constructor overload just to write a successful test case.  I feel like I just violated some coding principals to get the result I wanted, is this a common practice for testing?  I just started with automated unit testing this week so I am not sure if I just got my first lesson in Test Driven Development or if this is a one off workaround that shouldn't be done in the future?

Comment: @HunterNelson this is probably one of those grey areas where there are arguments either way. But I've found the easiest way to write testable code is to abstract out dependencies as much as possible, it's far easier to mock something you know about, than something you don't. As far as I know this doesn't violate any coding principles either, but it most likely bolsters the S, I and D in the SOLID principles.